# Single jar vs Multiple jars - performance benefits

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, maven, jvm

I have an application which is deployed into Jetty but is not packaged into single war file. Contrary, it is stored as a folder. There are quite a lot of dependencies in war/WEB-INF/lib folder which I am thinking of merging into one jar.

Are there any performance benefits that I would get by doing so?

Comment: I would try both and time it. My hunch is the difference would be minor. But I may be wrong.

Answer (score 2):

It does not matter. I do not know about jetty but all other servers I know extract archives anyway, i.e. store war/ear files in temporary directory in extracted form.

Comment: and so the not-packed version would be better, since it doesn't need to unpack / extract files ?

Answer (score 1):

@markovuksanovic: performance should not really matter or very insignificant.
Jar file is meant for archiving set of meaningful collection of classes and resources...that is all...